# Replace value of a key in Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I do the following, but have the new_key appear in the same spot as the old_key was before? So the solution would look like:

```
{ 'ONE: 'one', 2:'two', 3:'three' }
```

Example:

```
dict[new_key] = dict[old_key]
    del dict[old_key]
```

Or in 1 step:

```
dict[new_key] = dict.pop(old_key)
```

which will raise KeyError if dict[old_key] is undefined. Note that this will delete dict[old_key].

```
>>> dict = { 1: 'one', 2:'two', 3:'three' }
>>> dict['ONE'] = dict.pop(1)
>>> dict
{2: 'two', 3: 'three', 'ONE': 'one'}
>>> dict['ONE'] = dict.pop(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 1
```

Comment: Remember that python dics are unordered groups of pairs `<key,value>`

Comment: Perhaps you want a named tuple, rather than a dictionary.  
Or you can sort your dictionary by key as you iterate over it.  
What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: collections has "OrderedDict" you may want that ----otherwise, you may get change in order just by adding new keys, even without deleting

Comment: `which will raise KeyError if dict[old_key] is undefined.` In that case it doesn't make sense to replace the non-existing key anyway. What is the problem with your proposed solution? (Besides missing order in Python `dict`s if you actually meant that)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered; don't ever rely on the ordering of keys. Therefore, replacing a key "to preserve order" doesn't make sense.

It's possible to do this with an `OrderedDict`, but it requires inserting all keys into a new ordered dictionary (because you cannot insert into the middle of an `OrderedDict`).

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the key using the method you described, but keep in mind that Python dicts are semantically unordered:

```
my_dict[new_key] = my_dict.pop(old_key)
```